# Moving Laravel 4 files to Production Server FTP (cPanel)

Tags: ftp, laravel-4, cpanel

I've successfully installed laravel version 4.1.24 (using softaculous) on my production server and now I want to move my application from my local machine to the production server (cPanel-type web hosting) but I'm having a bugger of a time figuring out how to do it. I've found a few forums online discussing similar problems but nothing has helped me yet. Which files do I need to move? Can I move them via FTP? I'm not familiar with any other method.

**More detail:** When I copy over all of the critical files in the "app" and "public" folders I get an error that it doesn't recognize my model classes. When I copy over everything (including "vendor" and "bootstrap" it still doesn't recognize my model classes). Someone's has to have done this before. What did you do?

**Update:**
I'm getting closer to the problem. I started with fresh installations on both my local and production environments and moved/overwrote files for the following folders:
/app/controllers
/app/models
/app/views

Also moved/overwrote the app/filters.php file. Besides the "public" folder this encompasses pretty much my entire application so far.

I then copied over a super-slimmed-down app/routes.php file that has only one route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
$users = User::where('id', '<' ,'100')->whereNotNull('first_name')->get();

    foreach($users as $user){
        echo $user->first_name . '<br>';
    }
});
```

This worked as expected on both the local and production! I then changed the route to the following:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
$cars = Car::where('id', '<' ,'100')->get();

    foreach($cars as $car){
        echo $car->name . '<br>';
    }
});
```

This works just fine on the local environment but in the production it returns a "Class 'Car' not found" error. This is my problem and I think that user2094178 was onto something when he/she mentioned running "composer dump-autoload". Any idea how to do that remotely with cPanel?

**Update #2**
I found this thread: [How to avoid using php composer dump-autoload with laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186605/how-to-avoid-using-php-composer-dump-autoload-with-laravel-4). This seems to be addressing exactly the same issue. Except that all of my models are already in the "models" folder so the line `app_path().'/models',` should already be loading my classes. Right?

Also, I've found the "bootstrap/autoload.php" file that says this in the comments:

> "Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for our application... We'll require it into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the loading of any our classes 'manually'."

This is followed by:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

I'm scared to modify this file because I have no idea what I'm doing in there. This has then lead me to a few other files with the same lack of direction. Any ideas?

**Update 3:**
Looks like Laravel 3 had something like this: http://three.laravel.com/docs/loading. I need to find out how to do it in Laravel 4.

Comment: Why do you need a separate installation of Laravel in your local and production, why not install and setup Laravel on your local, then transfer the whole project via FTP afterwards.

Comment: @har2vey Have you tried doing transferring everything? I'm curious if it worked for you because it didn't work for me. I'm wondering if there's stuff that's specific to my local machine that needs to be changed. Any ideas what that might be? ... but I'm at my wit's end so I'm sure I'll give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have identicals local and production server directory structure? If yes, is your production php server compatible with the minimum required to laravel 4? If you are using cPanel and FTP, chances are it is not.

Comment: You need to check the PHP version and the required extensions (mycrypt, etc) of your hosting as well, older hosting that runs on cPanel might be running on version 5.2

Comment: @user2094178 the directory structure looks identical as far as I can tell. Also, yes it installed laravel 4.1.24 (using softaculous).

Comment: @har2vey not familiar with the mycrypt extension. Please expound. Also, the server is running version php version 5.3.28.

Comment: When I receive a not found controller class from laravel, it means I forgot to run composer dump-autoload. Also, if you installed laravel via softaculous on the production server it means the generated autoload files won't match, since you are uploading from local.

Comment: @user2094178 I think you're onto something there with composer. I'll look into that.

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186605/how-to-avoid-using-php-composer-dump-autoload-with-laravel-4. Might be the answer.

Comment: @user2094178: I got it working by getting the host company to enable SSH and running "composer dumpt-autoload". Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. I'd still like to know how to do this without having to run composer every time I add a class!

Comment: If that's your issue, then you can follow the suggestion from the thread to add the directories of your class into global.php

Comment: @har2vey my directory was already listed in the global.php file ("app/models" folder). Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I receive a not found controller class from laravel, it means I forgot to run `composer dump-autoload`.

To avoid it, open the file `app/start/global.php` and certify you have the desired path within `ClassLoader::addDirectories array`.

It worked fine to me without the need of `composer dump-autoload`. Since it doesn't scan subdirs, you may regret using it when you start to organize your models and controllers by dirs.

If you are willing to consider using namespaces to free yourself from `composer dump-autoload`, please read the following:

https://github.com/daylerees/autoload-demo

Comment: Got my hosting company to enable SSH and runing `composer dump-autoload` worked. Thanks! Regarding your other suggestion: all of my model classes are in the `app/model` directory (not in a subdirectory) which is by default listed in `app/start/global.php` `ClassLoader::addDirectories array`. It still didn't work for me. I'll look into the thread you posted below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You must copy all the files, and be careful with the conf/local, mabe you have some configuration on your local that isn't in your genral file.

Remember you need to have installed

PHP >= 5.3.7
MCrypt PHP Extension
PHP JSON extension

If you are going to work developing web apps, you should learn a version control software, [git](http://git-scm.com/), [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

With git, moving your project to production is as easy as typing a command in your shell and you can keep a copy of your code safe in another place like [github](https://github.com/) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org).

You also have more complex deployment software like [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/), they give you full control of your deployments.

Even you can use a php as a service place like http://fortrabbit.com/

I recommend you any of this much more than using ftp.

Comment: Thanks. har2vey also mentions the mcrypt extension. I'm not familiar with that file. What do I do with it? Also, the server is running php version 5.3.28. So will that not work? Finally, I've been avoiding learning version control software like git but it sounds like I really should go there. I know it'll pay off in the long run but I've been avoiding the up-front time investment.

Comment: if you have ssh access, try `php -i | grep mcrypt` to check else write a file like info.php and add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check it from the browser.
if you work with laravel or other similar framework it's a must learning git, i also recommend you to put your projects in a hosting with ssh acces, and yes you should learn some linux console basics too.

Comment: So I should check to see that the file exists? Where should it be? Good advice with git and linux but I don't think that will solve my immediate problem.